# ArcGIS SceneLayer attributes don't match Attribute Table

Tags: arcgis-pro, web-scene

I am working with 3D multipatch data (representing buildings) both locally and on our Uni's server and I am having some troubles. (this is my first time working with data on a server). Here's my problem:

I downloaded the data from our city's administration and everything was fine, however, I realized I need another attribute field for visualization in my Web Scene. So I ran a Python script locally to update 1 existing field and 1 field I just added in the attribute table.
When I look at the table in ArcGIS Pro, the script worked as planned. However, when I upload the Layer (via the "Share as Web Layer"- menu) and look at the data in a Web Scene, the Attributes don't match up anymore. The corresponding "feature layer (hosted)" shows the correct values, the "scene layer (hosted)" has different ones. I can't figure out how that could happen.

Does anyone have an idea?

[image: Published Feature Layer]

[image: Published Scene Layer after trying to add color]

[image: Published Scene Layer 2]

Comment: Share a few screenshots for a better understanding. And is it a standalone server or ArcGIS Portal? What happens when you share the scene layer directly as a web scene to the server?

Comment: As far as I know it is ArcGIS Portal. I attached two screenshots, one from the feature layer data and one from the scene layer. The column "DACHINF" is supposed to be all zeros or ones, which is not the case in the scene layer. The values go from 2 to 18.
I realize now that the problem only occurs when I try to apply a style to it (which is why I added the field in the first place). When I open the scene layer in a new web scene - the values are correct, but as soon as I try to color the building accorcing to the info, the values change.

Answer (score 0):

Try change FID to OBJECTID,
It works for me